# Creating a custom brand for Open Data

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

**Can we improve branding of OpenData?**

For example, see the screenshot:

[image]

We are buried with other generic networks. But looks at "Mathematica" and some others - they really stand out.

We can create a custom logo and color scheme. Additionaly, that logo would show up as the [Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

**Can the mods add some details about what is possible for improving the branding of OpenData, and also propose some way to make a cool logo (i.e. a contest or voting system)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the custom brand will be created when Open Data will leave the beta status... And for this to happen we need more traffic, questions and users.

Comment: This is exactly correct. Our [current beta site design](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/) is intentially generic. The main perks to graduation are: 1. a site design, and 2. elected (rather than appointed) moderators.